# How to get "next" and "previous" items in arrays in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm sorry I'm new to JavaScript(or ECMAscript) but I've wondered recently how to get previous or next elements in an Array in Javascript.
Here's an example.

```
var array = [ "item1", "item2", "item3", ]
var itemOfArray = "item2"
```

So now I want a way to get the "next" value in the array from `itemInArray`.
Basically, grab the index of `itemOfArray` in `array` and add to it. If the value is already at the last place of the array, go the first one. Vice verca for going backwards.

How do I do this in 100% Javascript?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Can't you store the index instead of the string value in the first place? Using `.indexOf` will break as soon as your array contains duplicate items.

Comment: What if you got multiple copies of the same string in your array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fetch the position of the string in `itemOfArray` with `array.IndexOf`

If the return value of that is the same as the length of the array, then next value is `arr[0]`

If the return value of that is the first element, then I assume to your logic for the previous value will be the last element of the array. So get `array[array.length - 1]`

Here is the code:

```
let next; 
let previous;
let position;

let array = [ "item1", "item2", "item3", ]
let itemOfArray = "item2";

position = array.indexOf(itemOfArray)
next = position === array.length - 1 ? array[0] : position++
previous = position === 0 ? array.length - 1 : position--
```

Answer (score 1):

You could get the position of the item and increment/decrement like this.

```
var pos = array.indexOf(itemOfArray);

var next = pos + 1;
var prev = pos - 1;

if (prev < 0)
  prev = array.length - 1;

if (next > array.length - 1)
  next = 0;
```

Comment: @user2864740 You're right, thank you for the suggestions.

Comment: If you would be looking for `'item2'` in `[ "item1", "item2", "item3", ]` you'll get `pos = 1` with `indexOf()`, then your `next` would be equal to `2` and (***what's important***) `pos` value will also be changed to `2`, then you'll get your `prev` equal to `1` (as your `pos` gets decremented back). Long story short, your solution is total mess.

Comment: If element doesn't exist in array, your solution will return `next = 0` and `prev = -2` which is, obviously, absolute nonesense.

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov Coding for that would make better code, but that has nothing to do with the question in this case.

Answer (score 1):

The [remainder operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder) is often useful to wrap around an integer range.

```
var arr = [ "item1", "item2", "item3" ]
var item = "item2"

// Choose 'current item' somehow.
// If the item does not exist, indexOf returns -1
// so initially clamp the to the first element in such a case.

var cur_index = Math.max(arr.indexOf(item), 0)

// The '+ arr.length' is only needed if decrementing (which can result in a negative number),
// however it can used in the positive case as well for uniformity.
// If arr.length is 0, the result is NaN.

var prev_index = (cur_index - 1 + arr.length) % arr.length;
var next_index = (cur_index + 1 + arr.length) % arr.length;

// If the indices are NaN (see above) the result is undefined.

console.log(arr[prev_index]);
console.log(arr[next_index]);
```

Comment: So, the answer for non-existent item and item found in the first position will be the same?

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov In the code above that is the case. It should be changed (ie. with a conditional) if different behavior is desired, eg. `var cur_index = arr.indexOf(item); cur_index = cur_index < 0 ? NaN : cur_index;` would make a missing item have no prev/next.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to get the index of the element

```
var itemOfArray = "item2"
```

...so you need to use the `indexOf()` function

```
var index = array.indexOf(itemOfArray);
```

Use a `ternary` operator to check if the index is last or fisrt index of array

#### Try it here

```js
var array = [ "item1", "item2", "item3", ]
var itemOfArray = "item2"

var index = array.indexOf(itemOfArray);

// check if index is the last or first index of array

var after = index === array.length - 1 ? 0 : index + 1;
var previous = index === 0 ? array.length - 1 : index - 1;

console.log( "Previous: " + array[previous] );  // -1 to get the previous

console.log( "After: " + array[after] );        // +1 to get the after
```

Comment: @user2864740, you are right, just updated it.